# Trigonometric Integral (Sine Integral)

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

How to evaluate the following integral ?
$$\boxed {\int_{0}^\infty \frac{\sin(t)}{t}\mathrm dt}  $$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_integral

Comment: see also here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SineIntegral.html